# slice and reshape MLMultiArray in IOS

Tags: ios, coreml, coremltools

I have a coreML model (converted from Keras) that produces output as a MLMultiArray of size (1,40,30,90)( e.g. name : finalOutput). This array is obtained from reshaping an internal tensor of dimension (1,10800,10)

I am not able to slice the ***finalOutput*** multiArray into three slices of dimensions (1,40,30,0:45) , ( 1,40,30,45:54) and (1,40,30,54:90).

these will then be reshaped into three subarrays  of dimensions 
(1,10800,5) , (1,10800) amnd (1,10800,4).

I am new to swift programming in iOS world. I can easily do this in python without issues.

How do is SLICE multiarrays and RESHAPE multiArrays in Swift for iOS ?

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no easy methods on MLMultiArray for slicing and reshaping. Maybe we'll something like this in iOS 12 but for the time being you'll have to do this sort of thing using pointer arithmetic.

Comment: yeah.. i resorted to coreml pipelines and used its function to perform operations on the tensors/Array datatypes within the model to find the final answer.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this [example](https://github.com/hollance/CoreMLHelpers/blob/master/CoreMLHelpers/MLMultiArray%2BHelpers.swift) which uses pointers to reshape